# Not Getting correct output in list view of android

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arraylist

I am parsing the value of a key `name` from a JSONArray and have to populate in the the `list view` of android activity.

I have JSON tree as

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "accounts",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://lavazzaindia--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/latest/accounts"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "analyticsReports",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://lavazzaindia--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/latest/analyticsReports"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "answers",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://lavazzaindia--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/latest/answers"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://lavazzaindia--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/latest/assets"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "assetStatuses",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://lavazzaindia--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/latest/assetStatuses"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "channelTypes",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://lavazzaindia--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/latest/channelTypes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "configurations",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://lavazzaindia--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/latest/configurations"
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
 }
```

I am using `for loop` to extract the value of name:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parentArr.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject finalObj = parentArr.getJSONObject(i);       //Getting each single object from JSON array Items
   String nameKey = finalObj.getString("name");            //Getting value of key(name) from each JSON Object
   System.out.println("name : "+nameKey);

   HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();         // tmp hash map for single data
   data.put("name",nameKey);                               //Adding each value of name to Hashmap key => value

   dataList.add(data);         //adding data to the datalist
}
```

Here `dataList` -> `ArrayList`

I am getting all `name` in the `Android Monitor` console using `Sysout`.

To view these `names` i am using the following code:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataList, 
         R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.name});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here `lv` -> `ListView`

This is my `activity_main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.spectrum_developer.resturldemo.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And `list_item.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But in emulator I am getting only top one value.
I have to show all values what I am getting in the `console` of `android studio`.

[image: output of jsonValue]

Can anybody correct me what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Are you able to scroll up and down? If yes, adjust the individual layout height to wrap content.

Comment: Post your activity and adapter code

Comment: @Sanoop It is `wrap_content` itself. I have added `activity` also. Please look into that.

Comment: @EKN adapter code was already posted, activity codes are added. help me out.

Comment: follow this....http://abhiandroid.com/ui/simpleadapter.html

Comment: ListView in ScrollView ? Obviously you shouldn't do this ... I bet on common problem with understanding asynchrouns call/multithreading - dataList is empty at the time of creating adapter ... but it's hard to guess without MCVE

Comment: Thanks a lot @Selvin. I've removed ScrollView tag and all values can be seen in ListView.

Answer (score 3):

I have checked your code and make a sample project using your code snippet. It is working properly. And there is no issues with your code.

I used Recycleview instead of list view(It is advanced). Please refer below code.This will help you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Change it to read from json
        arrayList.add("accounts");
        arrayList.add("analyticsReports");

        arrayList.add("answers");
        arrayList.add("assets");
        arrayList.add("assetStatuses");
        arrayList.add("channelTypes");
        arrayList.add("configurations");

        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(arrayList, MainActivity.this);
        RecyclerView rv;
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**SampleAdapter.java**

```
class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Activity mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    SampleAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, Activity context) {
        mContext = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }


    @Override
    public SampleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SampleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tvAward.setText(arrayList.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvAward;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvAward = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);


        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer suggested by [Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin).

I've just removed ScrollView tag from `activity_main.xml` and I got the following output.

[image: output]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the for loop to extract the value of the name to,

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList();     
for (int i = 0; i < parentArr.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject finalObj = parentArr.getJSONObject(i);       
       String nameKey = finalObj.getString("name");            
       System.out.println("name : "+nameKey);                            
       dataList.add(nameKey);         
    }
```

I think there is no need to add each nameKey in each hashMap. Just a List of string with all nameKey is enough to input the adapter.